# How to use curl to test API gateway's request-based Lambda authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm following the [EXAMPLE: Create a request-based Lambda authorizer function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-lambda-function-create) to build a lambda authorizer using request-based method.

The configuration of the authorizer looks like:

[image]

Just wondering how to test it using curl?

I did try:

```
 curl -X GET \
  "https://XXX.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/pets?QueryString1=QueryString1" \
  -H "headerauth1: headerauth1" \
  -H "StageVar1: StageVar1"
```

However, got the `{"message":"Unauthorized"}` response.

Comment: What’s the code for your Lambda?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks, for the auth02, exactly the same as the `EXAMPLE: Create a request-based Lambda authorizer function` part. For the pets api, I imported from the API gateway demo.